# How do I go from the left to the right of the equal sign? $ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k \cdot 2^{n - 1 - k} =2^n - n - 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've just done an excercise and got what's on the left hand side of the equals sign which is correct but in the answers they say that there are two ways of writing it as shown below. How would I go from my expression on the left side of the equals sign to the expression on the right?

$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k \cdot 2^{n - 1 - k} =2^n - n - 1$

Answer (score 0):

### HINT:

Let $S(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{-k}=\frac{1-x^{-n}}{1-x^{-1}}$. (Sum of Geometric Sequence)

Then, $S'(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}-kx^{-k-1}=\left(\frac{1-x^{-n}}{1-x^{-1}}\right)'.$

$$\therefore2^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k\cdot2^{-k-1}=-2^nS'(2).$$